# How to calculate the centerline velocity inside a pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity

Well, I was reading about fluid-solid/structure interaction models for make a simulation in COMSOL, and in few papers about it [[1]](http://stroke.ahajournals.org/content/37/5/1195) I find an expression about the *centerline velocity*. I understand the concept: it's the velocity of the central part of a fully developed velocity profile for a cylindrical pipe. I found an interesting expression for its calculation, but I don't know how to get it, the expression is:

$$ U_{inlet} = U t^2 \sqrt{(0.04-t^2)^2 + (0.1t)^2} $$

where I've got a value for $U$ in $[m/s]$ and $t$ is in seconds.

But today reading an example made in Comsol [[2]](http://www.comsol.com/model/fluid-structure-interaction-361), from part of its own documentation I found *almost* the same equation but different:

$$ u_{inlet}= \dfrac{Ut^2}{\sqrt{(0.04-t^2)^2 + (0.1t)^2}} $$

The coefficient values are the same, and the expression is very similar, but in the first paper I read, the term inside the square root was multiplying, and here is dividing, but I can't see clear why.

I tried to find out for sure checking the books available that I have: White (6th ed.), Streeter (8th ed.)  and one of computational fluid dynamics, but I have not found anything to help me. Someone here will have an idea?

Comment: It looks like it's just an empirical correlation. Could you add references to the papers?

Comment: @user3823992 I think so, I edited the question for add the references you asked.

Comment: I'd guess that it's the first paper that has a typo.  I've tried plotting the two cases and the division case makes a lot more sense.  It produces a rise-overshoot-decay shape.  Multiplying just causes the curve to increase constantly (over 100 m/s at 5 seconds!).

Comment: Well I was trying the Wolfram Alpha site with the function I asked. I plotted bot functions using an interval from -pi to pi and the first equation, without division case looks more as a parabolic profile meanwhile the second isn't continue at zero. This is because the division, you can't dive between zero. So, for me makes more sense the first one, but I want to know how you plotted them?

Comment: I used wolfram too (because lazy).  Parabolic makes sense a a spatial profile, not temporal (t stands for time here).  I should think that it would start at t=0.  As I noted before, the parabolic profile increases without limit.

Comment: @user3823992 You're right, it's in terms of time -_\ thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit as $t$ goes to $\infty$ for:

$$ u_{inlet}= \dfrac{Ut^2}{\sqrt{(0.04-t^2)^2 + (0.1t)^2}} $$

is $U$, which is more reasonable than $u_{inlet}$ going to $\infty$ for the first equation.

The first equation is definitely wrong.  The second equation is much more reasonable.

Comment: Better late than never ;)